# LINQ Cannot assign void to Implicitly Typed variable

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert this set of data to an object with help of LINQ but I am getting this error :

> Cannot assign void to Implicitly Typed variable

I can understand that I have to make use of `Select()` function but I am not able to figure out how to do it.

Data Set:

```
[Zip]   [Fips]  [County]    [StateAbbr] [StateName]
90210   12345   County1     CA      California
90210   12346   County2     CA      California
90210   12347   County3     CA      California
90210   12348   County4     CA      California
```

Code Snippet:

```
 var zipInfo = results.ForEach(z => new ZipInfoEntity{
        Zip = z.Zip,
        StateName = z.StateName,
        StateAbbr = z.StateAbbr,
        FipsCountyInfo = new List<FipsCountyInfoEntity>{
            new FipsCountyInfoEntity {
                Fips = z.Fips,
                County = z.County
            }
        }
    });

public ZipInfoEntity
{
    public string Zip {get;set;}
    public string StateName {get;set;}
    public string StateAbbr {get;set;}
    public IList<FipsCountyInfoEntity> FipsCountyInfo {get;set;}
}

public FipsCountyInfoEntity
{
    public string Fips {get;set;}
    public string County {get;set;}
}
```

What I am ultimately trying to achieve is an object of ZipInfoEntity. 
If you will see my DataSet, it has Zip, StateAbbr and StateName same for all rows. County and Fips are changing.

So my final object should be like

```
{
   Zip: "90210",
   StateAbbr: "CA",
   StateName: "California",
   FipsCountyInfo: [
        {Fips: "12345", County: "County1"}, 
        {Fips: "12346", County: "County2"},
        ...]
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what your final object structure would look like? Should there be one zip info entity with a list of multiple county info objects or do you indeed want one zip info entity for each row of your data set?

Comment: @Chris  updated question.

Comment: So you need to use `GroupBy` and not any select or whatever

Comment: @m.rogalski Could you help me out with that ?

Comment: I assume you are guaranteed that only Fips and County will change and that the other fields will be identical between rows?

Comment: @siddharth check my edited answer, made it to use `GroupBy` so that you can generate this kind of Json as you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `ForEach` returns `void` and you're trying to assign it to some variable which you cannot do in C#.

So to begin you should have something like this :

```
var zipInfo = results.Select(z => new ZipInfoEntity{
    Zip = z.Zip,
    StateName = z.StateName,
    StateAbbr = z.StateAbbr,
```

And here you try to assign an object of type `FipsCountyInfoEntity` to a collection of `FipsCountyInfoEntity` ( `IList<FipsCountyInfoEntity>` ). And you should instead assign new collection :

```
    FipsCountyInfo = new List<FipsCountyInfoEntity>(new FipsCountyInfo[] { 
        new FipsCountyInfoEntity{
            Fips = z.Fips,
            County = z.County
        }
    }
});
```

Or change that property to be of type `FipsCountyInfoEntity` and use it as you did :

```
    FipsCountyInfo = new FipsCountyInfoEntity{
        Fips = z.Fips,
        County = z.County
    }
});
```

**EDIT :**
As specified in the comment, to retrieve only one element you can use `FirstOrDefault()` Linq method at the end eg. :

```
var zipInfo = results.Select(z => new ZipInfoEntity{
    // ... same code as above
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or :

```
var zipInfo = results.FirstOrDefault(z => new ZipInfoEntity{
    // ... same code as above
    return true; // needs to return true on object you want to return
});
```

**EDIT2 :**
To get only one element with the collection of `FipsCountyInfoEntity` I would suggest doing something like such :

```
var zipInfo = results.Select(e => new ZipInfoEntity 
    {
        Zip = z.Zip,
        StateName = z.StateName,
        StateAbbr = z.StateAbbr,
        FipsCountyInfo = results.Select(z => new FipsCountyInfoEntity
        {
            Fips = z.Fips,
            County = z.County
        }
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or using `GroupBy` :

```
var zipInfo =  results.GroupBy(e => new { e.Zip, e.StateName, e.StateAbbr }).Select(e => new ZipInfoEntity
        {
            Zip = e.Key.Zip,
            StateName = e.Key.StateName,
            StateAbbr = e.Key.StateAbbr,
            FipsCountyInfo = e.Select(c => new FipsCountyInfoEntity
            {
                Fips = c.Fips,
                County = c.County
            }).ToList()
        });
```

Comment: This will return IEnumerable<ZipInfoEntity> but I just want ZipInfoEntity object with List<FipsCountyInfoEntity>

Comment: @siddharth I've edited my answer, should be exactly what you specified.

Answer (score 1):

Property `FipsCountyInfo` in `ZipInfoEntity` should be declared like this.

```
public ZipInfoEntity
{
    public string Zip {get;set;}
    public string StateName {get;set;}
    public string StateAbbr {get;set;}
    public FipsCountyInfoEntity FipsCountyInfo {get;set;} // <-- use class, not IList
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your FipsCountryInfo list properly. FipsCountyInfo  is a list of FipsCountyInfoEntity and you are trying to assign a FipsCountyInfoEntity object to the list.

You need to replace this code :

```
FipsCountyInfo = new FipsCountyInfoEntity{
    Fips = z.Fips,
    County = z.County
}
```

With this :

```
FipsCountyInfo = new  List<FipsCountyInfoEntity>(){ new FipsCountyInfoEntity{
    Fips = z.Fips,
    County = z.County
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do you:

```
var output = new ZipInfoEntity
{
    Zip = results.First().Zip,
    StateName = results.First().StateName,
    StateAbbr = results.First().StateAbbr,
    FipsCountyInfo = new List<FipsCountyInfoEntity>( 
        results.Select(z=>
            new FipsCountyInfoEntity {
                Fips = z.Fips,
                County = z.County
            }
        )
    )
}
```

`results.First()` just gets the first item in the list. We use this since we can get the first three fields just from the first object. Then when creating the `FipsCountyInfo` list I then loop through your results set, constructing an object for each entry.

It should be noted that this assumes that the `Zip`, `StateName` and `StateAbbr` will be identical across all the rows. If they aren't (ie you have details for more than one zip in the result set) then this will give unexpected results and you'll want to use group by instead to get an `IEnumerable<ZipInfoEntity>` from the results.